# Char pointer equivalent in c#

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I am converting c++ code into c#, and char in c++ takes 8 bits while in c# takes 16 bits. I don't know about char*, So

What is the equivalent of `char *` in `C#`, Do i use `byte[]` or `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] StringBuilder`  and also tell me whether the equivalent of `char` from `C++` to `C#` is `byte` or `string`?

Comment: What are you trying to *achieve*? What data do you want to store?

Comment: If you are talking about platform invokes, it depends. It can be `ref sbyte` or `string`.

Comment: Actually i am converting c++ code into c# and i encountered char* and char, but in c# char is of two 16 bits, and i don't know about char* ?

Comment: if you are rewriting a project that was written in C and you are now writing in C#, depending on what the char * is used for, you can use byte[], char[] or even String

Comment: Impossible to advise you accurately unless you show more information.

Answer (score 2):

For an input parameter it could be a `string` or a `byte[]`, depending on the meaning of the parameter. If it represents a sequence of characters then use `string`. If the parameter is a buffer to some arbitrary data then it's most likely a `byte[]`.

However in C/C++ a `char *` can also be an output parameter, such as in the `sprintf` function. In that case a `StringBuilder` or a `byte[]` would be the equivalent types, depending again on the meaning of the parameter.

With regards the `char` datatype in C#, please keep in mind that a `char` in C# means character, whereras the meaning the C/C++ is closer to that of a `byte` in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand the question correctly but C# too have Char type http://www.dotnetperls.com/char

Answer (score 0):

It depends:

1. `char *ptr` should be replaced with `string` if it acts as a string
   container (like commonly used in c).
2. If what matters is the value in it and to bound its range in-between `[-127,128]` use `char[]` or `byte[]`  e.g. `char[] array1 = { 'b', 'c', 'a' };`